# Drop down menu with on click toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, menu, toggle

I am attempting to create a drop down menu which activates on click rather than on hover. So far I have the on click working with a little javascript, but whilst the sub menus show well and if another menu is clicked other submenus hide, I can't work out how to hide a sub menu if its parent is clicked.

EG in this [JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8qPvp/4/)  I can click on "parent 1" to reveal its children and when I click on "parent 2" parent 1's children hide and Parent 2's children show. But if Parent 1's children show I want to be able to hide them by clicking on Parent 1 again, (or even better anywhere outside the children)

I have seen examples working where each parent and sub menu is given individual classes or ids. I want to avoid that as it needs to work in a cms.

Here's the basic code I have

The HTML:

```
<div>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Parent 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Parent 1 &raquo; Child 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Parent 1 &raquo; Child 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Parent 1 &raquo; Child 1</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Parent 2</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Parent 2 &raquo; Child 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Parent 2 &raquo; Child 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Parent 2 &raquo; Child 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Parent 3</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Parent 3 &raquo; Child 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Parent 3 &raquo; Child 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Parent 3 &raquo; Child 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("li").click(function () {
        $('li > ul').hide();
        $(this).children("ul").toggle();
    });
});
```

CSS is probably not necessary, but its on the fiddle if needed

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this way.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("li").click(function () {
        //Toggle the child but don't include them in the hide selector using .not()
        $('li > ul').not($(this).children("ul").toggle()).hide();

    });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QxRL9/)**

Comment: Thanks PSL that's bang on.

Answer (score 2):

check this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/Kritika/SZwTg/1/

```
               $(document).ready(function () {
                      $("li").click(function () {
                          $('li > ul').not($(this).children("ul")).hide();
                          $(this).children("ul").toggle();
                             });
                        });
```

or

```
                $(document).ready(function () {
                     $("li").click(function () {
                         var submenu=$(this).children("ul");
                         $('li > ul').not(submenu).hide();
                         submenu.toggle();
                         });
                    });
```

on click of "parent 1" it reveals its children and when you  click on "parent 2" parent 1's children hide and Parent 2's children show. and if  Parent 1's children show you wil be able to hide them by clicking on Parent 1 again.

Comment: This also does exactly what I want, not sure which would be best, hope you don't mind me giving a big green tick to the first answer, It came in first.

Answer (score 1):

Better to use slideToggle at the place of toggle:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("li").click(function () {
    $('li > ul').not($(this).children("ul")).hide();
    $(this).children("ul").slideToggle('slow');
});
```

});