# Javascript Onclick Menu

Tags: jquery, css, menu, onclick

I used this demo:

[Drop down menu with on click toggle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17388122/drop-down-menu-with-on-click-toggle)

To make this:

http://jsfiddle.net/q0m4mk5o/

The only thing I need, is to make sure the submenu, is also being displayed horizontally. But I do not have enough understanding of CSS to make it work. Also, I am creating this for learning purposes.

I think it may have something to do with this bit:

```
.testul li ul {
display: none;
list-style: none;
position: absolute;
left: 0;
}
.testul li ul li {
list-style: none;
white-space: nowrap;
height: 24px;
line-height: 24px;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#c8bfb0, #f5efe6);
border-bottom: 1px solid #d3c7b6;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "is also being displayed horizontally"?

Comment: Do you want a new "row" below the main menu instead a "column"?

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Do you want the `li` to display horizontally (from left to right, next to each other) instead of vertically?

Comment: Also I want to point out: `li > ul` would not work because you cannot "go up a level" with CSS selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `display: inline-block` as:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/q0m4mk5o/5/)

```
.testul li ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
    height: 24px;
    line-height: 24px;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#c8bfb0, #f5efe6);
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d3c7b6;
}
```