# How do I make my dropdown menu toggle off when I click it a second time?

Tags: javascript, html, css, toggle, accordion

I'm new to JavaScript, and I pieced together some code I found to make a horizontal accordion, but I haven't been able to get it to close. Basically I don't know how to put it on toggle.

```
$(function () {

$(".item").on("click", function () {
  $(this)
    .next().show().animate({width: "12%"})
    (".info").hide()
    .animate({width: "0"});
});

});
```

Here's my codepen:

http://codepen.io/SideSlaw/pen/zobJYO

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Drop down menu with on click toggle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17388122/drop-down-menu-with-on-click-toggle)

Comment: have you tried using `slideToggle`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `tansition` instead `animate` and toggle the class `.active`, it removes and add the class every click. and some adjustment with the css to make the transition smooth. see example below:

```js
$(function () {

  $(".item").on("click", function () {
    $(this)
      .next().toggleClass('active');
  });
  
});
```

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
  background: white;
  color: #D74F33;
}

section {
  width: 1900px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  position: fixed;
  left:-8px;
}
.item{
  width:9%; 
  height: 40px;
  float: left;
  border-right: 3px solid #D74F33;
  font: 20px monospace;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #333;
  transform: skew(-20deg);
  -webkit-transform: skew(-20deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(-20deg);
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

.info{
  float: left;
  width:0%;
  height: 40px;
  background: #4B3E4D;
  visibility: hidden;
  font: 20px monospace;
  background-color: gr;
  transform: skew(-20deg);
  -webkit-transform: skew(-20deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(-20deg);
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  transition: width ease-out .3s, visibility ease-out .3s;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow:hidden;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
.info.active{
  visibility: visible;
  width:12%;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <section>
  <div class="item"> about ►</div>
  <div class="info">lab  |  research</div>

  <div class="item"> people ►</div>
  <div class="info">current  |  alumni</div>
  
</section>
  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>

    <script src="js/index.js"></script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if your dropdown is active or not. So add a class="active" if it is open. This class doesn't need have any style, it's just for our script to know that it is open

Here's [pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Womgwg?editors=1010)

and here's the code:

```js
$(function () {

  
  // when to clicking on any item show the info about him and hide other info elemnet 
  $(".item").on("click", function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    if($(this).hasClass('active')){
      $(this)
      .next().show().animate({width: "12%"});
    }
    else{
      $(".info").hide()
      .animate({width: "0"});
    }
  });
});
```

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
  background: white;
  color: #D74F33;
}

section {
  width: 1900px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  position: fixed;
  left:-8px;
}
.item{
  width:9%; 
  height: 40px;
  float: left;
  border-right: 3px solid #D74F33;
  font: 20px monospace;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #333;
  transform: skew(-20deg);
  -webkit-transform: skew(-20deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(-20deg);
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

.info{
  float: left;
  width:0%;
  height: 40px;
  background: #4B3E4D;
  display: none;
  font: 20px monospace;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: gr;
  transform: skew(-20deg);
  -webkit-transform: skew(-20deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(-20deg);
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Horizontal Accordion </title>
  
  
  
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

  
</head>

<body>
  <section>
  <div class="item"> about ►</div>
  <div class="info">lab  |  research</div>

  <div class="item"> people ►</div>
  <div class="info">current  |  alumni</div>
  
</section>
  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>

    <script src="js/index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the flow of your animation.

On click first close if anything is opened and then open with animation.

Edited your pen little bit to achieve this 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/woOEgx

```
$(".item").on("click", function () {
    $(".info")
      .animate({width: "0"}).hide();
    $(this)
      .next().show().animate({width: "12%"});
});
```